# Understanding Memory Overhead for Objects in Spark and JVM

Tags: apache-spark, memory, memory-management, jvm

I'm delving into Apache Spark's memory management and trying to understand the overhead associated with storing objects, especially considering Spark runs on the JVM. A colleague of mine argues that due to Spark utilizing the JVM, there are substantial memory overheads involved. He cited an example stating that each single-character string in Spark would occupy more than 40 bytes of memory because of the JVM overhead. However, I believe that Spark stores data in a specialized format where a string in Spark is not directly equivalent to a string in the JVM, thanks to optimizations like Tungsten among others.

To shed some light on this, I attempted to measure the size of DataFrames but found it to be a non-trivial task, and the results seemed quite odd to me:

```scala
val df = spark.range(100000000).selectExpr("cast(id as string) as x").repartition(1)
SizeEstimator.estimate(df) // Resulted in 4mb

val df2 = spark.range(100000000).selectExpr("concat(cast(id as string),'z') as x").repartition(1)
SizeEstimator.estimate(df2) // Also resulted in 4mb
```

Both DataFrames, despite having seemingly different potential memory footprints (one without additional char, and the other with additional char), ended up with the same estimated size.

My questions are:

1. How accurate is the JVM's perception of object memory overhead in the context of Spark? Does Spark indeed optimize the storage of such objects to a significant extent?
2. How do Spark's optimizations like Tungsten influence the memory footprint of data stored in DataFrames or RDDs?

Any insights or resources that could help clarify these points would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I guess https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html would be a good starting place

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.